# Processing a file using 'awk' or any other command

Tags: shell

I have a file like:

```
Data:
1,2,3
Message
Data:
3,4,5
Message error
Error Due to data type mismatch
Data:
5,6,7
Message done
```

Here I have 10 records in input file. I would like to get 3 records in output file based on string 'Data:'.
My desired output file would be:

```
Data:|1,2,3|Message
Data:|3,4,5|Message error|Error Due to data type mismatch
Data:|5,6,7|Message done
```

I assume this can be done through 'awk' command. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

#### `sed` + `tr`

There is one way:

```
tr \\n \| | sed 's/|\($\|Data\)/\n\1/g;'
```

From

```
Data:
1,2,3
Message
Data:
3,4,5
Message error
Error Due to data type mismatch
Data:
5,6,7
Message done
```

This will render:

```
Data:|1,2,3|Message
Data:|3,4,5|Message error|Error Due to data type mismatch
Data:|5,6,7|Message done
```

#### pure `bash`

```
pot=""
while read line ;do
    [ "$line" ] && [ -z "${line%Data:}" ] &&
      [ "$pot" ] && echo "${pot% | }" && pot=""
    pot+="$line | "
  done
echo "${pot% | }"
```

Wich will render:

```
Data: | 1,2,3 | Message
Data: | 3,4,5 | Message error | Error Due to data type mismatch
Data: | 5,6,7 | Message done
```

#### One of many `perl` way

```
perl -nE 'chomp;if(/Data/){say$l if$l;$l=$_}else{$l.="|".$_};END{say$l}'

Data:|1,2,3|Message
Data:|3,4,5|Message error|Error Due to data type mismatch
Data:|5,6,7|Message done
```

But you could do same using many and many different ways!

#### Or even `sed` only!?

```
sed '/Data/ba;${H;ba;};bb;:a;x;s/\n/|/g;/./p;s/.*//;x;:b;/^Data/h;/^Data/!H;;d'
```

Wich will render:

```
Data:|1,2,3|Message
Data:|3,4,5|Message error|Error Due to data type mismatch
Data:|5,6,7|Message done
```

too...

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`

```
awk -F '\n' -vOFS='|' -vRS='Data:' '/./{NF--; printf "%s%s\n", p,$0};{p=RT}' file
Data:|1,2,3|Message
Data:|3,4,5|Message error|Error Due to data type mismatch
Data:|5,6,7|Message done
```

Or more generally

```
awk 'BEGIN{z=getline n < ARGV[1]};
{z=getline n < FILENAME; printf "%s%s", $0, n ~ /Data/ || !z? "\n": "|"}' file 
Data:|1,2,3|Message
Data:|3,4,5|Message error|Error Due to data type mismatch
Data:|5,6,7|Message done
```

Answer (score 0):

This leaves trailing '|', but that's easy to fix:

```
awk '/^Data:/ && NR>1 {printf "\n"}1' ORS=\| input; echo
```